# Why there is so much ESCs in perldoc?

Tags: perl, freebsd

I am using FreeBSD 9.1.

When I type 'perldoc perl' then:

```
    PERL(1)               User Contributed Perl Documentation              PERL(1)



ESC[1mNAMEESC[0m
       perl - The Perl 5 language interpreter

ESC[1mSYNOPSISESC[0m
       ESC[1mperl ESC[22m[<C2> ESC[1m-sTtuUWXESC[22m<C2> ]      [<C2> ESC[1m-hvESC[22m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-VESC[22m[:ESC[4mconfigvarESC[24m]<C2> ]
            [<C2> ESC[1m-cwESC[22m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-dESC[22m[ESC[1mtESC[22m][:ESC[4mdebuggerESC[24m]
<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-DESC[22m[ESC[4mnumber/listESC[24m]<C2> ]
            [<C2> ESC[1m-pnaESC[22m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-FESC[4mESC[22mpatternESC[24m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-lESC[22m[ESC[4moctalESC[24m]<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-0ESC[22m[ESC[4moctal/hexadecimalESC[24m]<C2> ]
            [<C2> ESC[1m-IESC[4mESC[22mdirESC[24m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-mESC[22m[ESC[1m-ESC[22m]ESC[4mmoduleESC[24m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-MESC[22m[ESC[1m-ESC[22m]ESC[4m'module...'ESC[24m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m-f
ESC[22m<C2> ]
            [<C2> ESC[1m-C<C2> [ESC[4mnumber/listESC[24m]<C2> ESC[22m]      [<C2> ESC[1m-SESC[22m<C2> ]      [<C2> ESC[1m-xESC[22m[ESC[4mdirESC[24m]<C2> ]
            [<C2> ESC[1m-iESC[22m[ESC[4mextensionESC[24m]<C2> ]
            [<C2> [ESC[1m-eESC[22m|ESC[1m-EESC[22m]<C2> ESC[4m'command'ESC[24m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[1m--ESC[22m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[4mprogramfileESC[24m<C2> ]<C2> [<C2> ESC[4margumentESC[24m<C2> ]...

ESC[1mGETTING HELPESC[0m
       The ESC[4mperldocESC[24m program gives you access to all the documentation that
       comes with Perl.  You can get more documentation, tutorials and
       community support online at <http://www.perl.org/>.

       If you're new to Perl, you should start by running "perldoc perlintro",
       which is a general intro for beginners and provides some background to
       help you navigate the rest of Perl's extensive documentation.  Run
       "perldoc perldoc" to learn more things you can do with ESC[4mperldocESC[24m.

       For ease of access, the Perl manual has been split up into several
       sections.
```

Why there is so much ESCs?
(If I type 'man perl' no this problam.)

Comment: For future visitors: `export LESS=mqeisz-2XR` .

Comment: Should be re-opened as it does fit the scope of questions related to programming *defined by the community* to include "software tools commonly used by programmers", which perldoc certainly is (and I'm baffled how anyone could see it as anything else...) @Useless et. al.

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing the raw `nroff` formatting (those escape sequences contain formatting information).

In my local installation, `man perldoc` says

> ```
>   perldoc looks up a piece of documentation in .pod format that is
>   embedded in the perl installation tree or in a perl script, and
>   displays it via "pod2man | nroff -man | $PAGER".
> ```

Try checking `nroff` is in your path, what `$PAGER` is set to, and playing around with the output format options (also listed in that man page).

Comment: The question is off-topic. However, maybe http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2009-December/208971.html will help.